# how to specify machine name for connecting through router

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, ftp

I have an ubuntu (14.04) desktop server "bdesktop" with 1 user "user1" that connects into a router. Inside the router I have a static local ip assigned to bdesktop (192.168.1.2). The router provides me a static website asdf.com which is an interface to the router, to which I can connect and access from the internet.

My goal is to be able to log into user1@bdesktop through the internet from my laptop, but I dont know how to specify the right hostname for an ssh or ftp connection.

would I connect to it via something like:

> ftp://user1@bdesktop.asdf.com
>    or 
>   ftp://user1@bdesktop:asdf.com or something along these lines?

Apologies in advance for not knowing the proper language surrounding these protocols, first time diving into extra-lan networking issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most routers have a feature to configure it as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for certain protocols (e.g. HTTP or FTP).

You can set up the router to direct traffic for a certain protocol (FTP in your case) to a designated machine on your network. You access your server by connecting to the hostname or IP address of your router.
In your case that would be: ftp://user1@asdf.com or ftp://asdf.com

Check the user manual for your router to find out whether or not it has this feature and how to set it up

I have a `Thomson Gateway TG585` and they call it `Game & Application Sharing`. It allows me to set up an HTTP or FTP server (it lists a dozen other protocols).